# JQuery - Slide Example

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to perform a simple slide motion on an HTML element. JQuery is already available on the site in question so the next logical step for me was to look at their documentation.

[JQuery - Slide down](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide)

When I check out their demo however, it doesn't seem to be functioning. In firebug they have an error;

```
missing ) after argument list
wyciwyg://0/http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide
Line 18
```

Whilst the error seems simple, I can't work out how to correct it (On thier site by editing the JS). On my own site using the same example an error is found in the JQuery 1.4.2 script itself;

```
jQuery.easing[specialEasing || defaultEasing] is not a function
file:///home/gav/ee-workspaces/web/site/php/jquery-1.4.2.js
Line 5854
```

I don't mean to sound lazy / rude but what's going on? Is the JQuery site and newest release actually broken, I doubt it, what am I doing wrong? I'm a CS grad with no real web dev experience so I'm not used to this method of debugging, where should I start with this?

Thanks,

Gav

Comment: In your site, is the easing plugin available ? If not, get it http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Easing

Comment: Did you include jqueryui 1.8 on your Site? See a working demo here: http://jsbin.com/umucu4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look [here](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) for a working example.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error

```
jQuery.easing[specialEasing || defaultEasing] is not a function
file:///home/gav/ee-workspaces/web/site/php/jquery-1.4.2.js
Line 5854
```

with jquery-1.4.2.js.

The simple solution is to replace your jquery include with:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or the latest version of Jquery available; http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js